# I am attempting to get area length and width from an image of a spring. When i run code it give me multiple objects, and draws multiple bounding boxes

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to get dimensions from photos of a spring. I attached the image of the spring which i got from an optical comparator. When i run the code i have and print out the results from area, it gives me the area of about eight or nine other objects, so i then added the bounding box and the spring is made up of a bunch of smaller bounding boxes. I am not sure if i am not understanding the concept of heirarchy of what but i have good looking images of grayscale then to threshold and the to canny edge finder so i am not sure what i am missing here. I have also tried to run the code on other images and it does the same thing, it give multiple bounding boxes around single objects. let me know what you think

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read Image
img = cv2.imread("springNpng.png")
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
edged = cv2.Canny(thresh, 30, 200)

contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)

#cnt = contours
#M = cv2.moments(cnt)
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print(area)
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)


cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("edged", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

compression spring from optical comparator:

[image: 1]

Comment: Why are you using Canny? Have you taken a look at the results from that step?

Comment: Canny is not good in this situation.  Threshold, then use morphology to close up the spring or blur and threshold again to do the same. Then get your contour. Or get the convex hull of the spring after thresholding. But not Canny.

Comment: I was mistaken; minAreaRect does not accept a binary mask as an alternative to a contour. some other OpenCV functions do take a contour or a mask.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach your problem in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold
- Optional Morphology close and/or open to remove outliers
- Invert threshold
- Convert the threshold image to points
- Get the convex hull of the points
- Get the rotated rectangle of the convex hull and its parameters
- Draw the convex hull and rotated rectangle on a copy of the input
- Save the hull and rotated rect image

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('spring.png')
print(img.shape)

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert
thresh = 255 - thresh

# convert to points
points = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))

# get convex hull
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)

# get rotated rectangle
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(hull)

# get parameters of rect
(center), (width,height), angle = rect

# correct angle
if angle < -45:
    angle = (90 + angle)
else:
    angle = angle

print('width:', width, 'height:', height, 'angle:', angle)

# draw convex hull and rotated rect on copy of input
outline = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(outline, [hull], True, (0,0,255), 2)
box = np.intp(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
cv2.polylines(outline, [box], True, (0,255,0), 2)

# save outline image
cv2.imwrite('spring_outline.png', outline)

# show outline image
cv2.imshow('outline', outline)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Convex Hull and Rotated Rect on Input (red is convex hull and green is rotated rectangle)

[image]

Parameters of Rotated Rectangle:

```
width: 505.5112609863281 height: 160.70016479492188 angle: 2.929425001144409
```

Comment: convex hull not required for input to minAreaRect. findContours is faster than np.where/np.argwhere

Comment: Thanks for the speed comment. I was just showing one method. As I said above in my comments, contour was the other way to go.